# Getting NaN for dividing each row value by row sum

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying something very simple, I got a Dataframe made of 1 and 0. I'm trying to divide each value in row by the sum of the row, so it will be weight so that the row sums to 1

trading_signal sample

```
             btc.  eth
2021/08/25.  1.    0
2021/08/26.  1.    1
2021/08/27.  0.    0
```

position expected output

```
             btc.  eth
2021/08/25.  1     0
2021/08/26.  0.5   0.5
2021/08/27.  0     0
```

I imagine it to just

```
positions = trading_signals / trading_signals.sum(axis=1)
```

But the positions df just populated with NaNs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to divide on `axis=0`, which is not the default with `/`. Use `div` instead:

```
df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

*NB. division by 0 will give you NaNs, so add `.fillna(0)` to fill with 0*

Comment: Ah wonderful didn't see div in the docs! Thaks a ton

Comment: Well, you have `div`, `add`, `sub`, `mul`… ;)

Answer (score 1):

Several options + comparison of running times:

1. apply

```
df.apply(lambda row: row / row.sum(axis=0), axis=1).fillna(0)

1.18 ms ± 5.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

2. transpose

```
(df.T / df.T.sum()).T.fillna(0)

1.54 ms ± 843 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

3. div

```
df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).fillna(0)

576 µs ± 354 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Option 3 has the lowest runtime - Probably because it makes the most of the vectoring capabilities of pandas-python

Same result for all of them:

[image]